# Set ip for traffic for all traffic incoming outgoing

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have host and 5 IPs set for that host.
I can access host by any of these IPs.
Any connection that was made from that host and dockers too are detected as from IP1
I have a docker on that host that I want to have an IP2. How can I set that docker so when any connection made from that docker to other external servers they get info about IP@ instead of IP1.
Thanks!

Comment: are you using docker, swarm or k8s?

Comment: have you tried port forwarding with dedicated IP? e.g. `docker run --port 1234:IP2:1234`

Comment: I have using docker as stated. Don't see how port forwarding will help? I just need to be identified as from IP2 and form IP1 when I access some external service from inside docker. For test I'm using requestbin.

Answer (score 1):

WHat have work for me at the end is to create docker network and add to iptables postrouting for that local range...

```
docker network create bridge-smtp --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source MYIP_ADD_HERE
docker run --rm --network bridge-smtp byrnedo/alpine-curl http://www.myip.ch
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you need to edit the routes on your machine. you can start by running these command to find out the current routes.

```
$ ip route show
default via 10.1.73.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
10.1.73.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.73.17 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
```

then you need to change the default route like this

```
ip route add default via ${YOUR_IP} dev eth0 proto static metric 100
```